# Converting Between Types JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why empty object + empty object equal to non-empty string, empty array + empty array equal to empty string and empty object + empty array equal to zero?

```
[] + [] = ""

[] + {} = "[object Object]"

{} + {} = "[object Object][object Object]"

{} + [] = 0
```

Comment: The really interesting one is the the 4th one. That one is doing extra casting. The rest are just calling `toString()` and are fairly expected..

Comment: @4castle not exactly, on the 4th one, the "object" is not really a type, just an empty code block...